# Inequality $3\cos(\frac{1}{3}\tan(\frac{1}{3}\sin(\frac{1}{3})))\leq\sum_{cyc}\cos(a\tan(b\sin(c)))\leq 3$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I'm proud to present one inequality of my work :

> Let $a,b,c>0$ such that $a+b+c=1$ then we have :
>   $$3\cos(\frac{1}{3}\tan(\frac{1}{3}\sin(\frac{1}{3})))\leq\sum_{cyc}\cos(a\tan(b\sin(c)))\leq 3$$

The goal was to create an inequality where the value are very condensed because we have :

$$3-3\cos(\frac{1}{3}\tan(\frac{1}{3}\sin(\frac{1}{3})))\leq 0.002$$

The RHS is obvious since $\cos(x)\leq 1 $ $ \forall x\in(-\infty,\infty)$

I have try power series but I'm stuck because the inequality is cyclic .

I think we can use Am-Gm and try to take the logarithm on each side but with this method I get nothing good .

Finally I try to use derivatives but it beginns very complicated since we composed elementary function .

If you have just a hint or a pedagogic method it would be cool.

Thanks a lot for sharing your time and knowledge .

Comment: The usual question: Can you provide any reason why this (randomly looking) inequality should be true?

Comment: I plottet the function, and I think the inequality is true.

Comment: Why the down-votes?

Comment: I think that it is not really very hard since $(1/3, 1/3, 1/3)$ is the unique best. Using the polynomial bounds for $\cos x, \tan x, \sin x$, we can get a polynomial lower bound of the expression, then we use Buffalo Way with computer algebraic systems (after homogenization) to prove the resulting inequality.